# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have PHP web service that is running every day since 2014. On average it sends 5000 messages per day. Since than I had 1 or 2 errors like this per month but last 10 days number of errors increased to 10 per day, number of messages increased slightly to 5200  and I haven't change anything for at least 2 years. Colleagues at my firm and at firm that is receiving those messages checked for errors in network and couldn't find any.
Last month my script send more than 50000 messages without error but now it stops after 1000 or less messages.
Error that I get is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\
src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php:146
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php(203): BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient-
>__doHttpRequest(Object(BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapRequest))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient.php(183): BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient-
>__doRequest2(Object(BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapRequest))
#2 [internal function]: BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://cis.api...', 'http://
www.apis...', 1, 0)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php(475): SoapClient->__call('sendMessage', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php(475): BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient->sendMessage(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP.php(403): Send_SOAP_mssg('Po\xC5\xA1tovana/i,<b...', '09596640-cbe0-4...', 18, 2,
'1111111', 'HR', 'Obavijest o sta...', 'https://cis.api. in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\BeSimpleSoap-master\src\BeSimple\So
apClient\SoapClient.php on line 146
```

Part of the script looks like this:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\NIAS\\BeSimpleSoap-master\\src\\" .$class_name . '.php';
}

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);


//Code for accessing remote protected OIB list.
$handle = curl_init();
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO         => $FINA_APIS_cert,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD  => $cert_password ,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT        => $cert_path,
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY         => $key_path,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION     => 4,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $OIB_URL
);

curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);

$OIB_File=(string)curl_exec($handle); //String of OIBs
if (curl_errno($handle)) {
  echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($handle);
}
curl_close($handle);    


$OIB_row = str_getcsv($OIB_File, "\n",","); //parse the rows
foreach($OIB_row as $Row){
    $Row = str_getcsv($Row, ","); //parse the items in rows 
    $Country_code = $Row[0];
    $OIB_array[$Row[1]] = TRUE;
}


// Open connection with MySQL Database
$link_mysql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "****", "****", "okp_php");

$rows_lines="";
$flag_split_saldo=1;

$input_file=scandir($full_path);//Scanning directory for files

foreach ($input_file as $input_name){
    if($input_name=="." || $input_name==".." || $input_name=="OIB")
        continue;

    $lines = file($full_path . $input_name);


    foreach($lines as $line){

        $line_row = explode(':', $line);
        $security_level=2;

        if(substr($input_name,0,7)=="naknade"){
            $OIB=$line_row[9];
            if (!isset($OIB_array[$OIB]))//searching for OIB in OIB list
                continue;

            $title="Obavijest o obračunatoj naknadi koju isplaćuje HZZO";
            if(empty($line_row[6])){
                $IBAN_tmp=$line_row[7].$line_row[8].'172700';
                $IBAN=IBAN_generator($IBAN_tmp);
            }
            else{
                $IBAN=$line_row[6];
            }

            $compensation = number_format($line_row[2],2);

            $TipPoruke=14;
            $UUID=gen_uuid();
            $security_level=2;
            $rows_lines ="Poštovana/i,<br />na Vaš račun " . $IBAN . " upućen je iznos od " . $compensation ." kuna za \"" . $line_row[5] . "\" za " . $line_row[0] . ". mjesec " . $line_row[1] . ". godine.<br /><br />Srdačan pozdrav,<br />Vaš HZZO";
        }

        else{
            continue;
        }


        Send_SOAP_mssg($rows_lines,$UUID,$TipPoruke,$security_level,$OIB,$Country_code,$title,$SERVICE_TEST,$SOAP_cert,$NAMESPACE_URI,$cert_password,$Attachment_file,$link_mysql);
        $Attachment_file="";
    }

    //Code for parsing only one saldo Dopunskog file
    if (substr($input_name,0,12)=="sal_web_pla_"){
        copy_file($flag_split_saldo,$full_path,$input_name,$destination);
        $flag_split_saldo=0;
    }
    else
    {
        $flag_split_saldo=1;
        copy_file($flag_split_saldo,$full_path,$input_name,$destination);
    }

}
//Close MySQL connection
mysqli_close($link_mysql); 
function Send_SOAP_mssg($rows_lines,$UUID,$TipPoruke,$security_level,$OIB,$Country_code,$title,$SERVICE_TEST,$SOAP_cert,$NAMESPACE_URI,$cert_password,$Attachment_file,$link_mysql){
        $date_time = date("c");
        $encoded_msg=base64_encode($rows_lines);
        $encodded = new SoapVar("<tns:KorisnickiPretinacPoruka xmlns:tns='http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/kp'
                    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                    xsi:schemaLocation='http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/kp ../schema/KorisnickiPretinacSchema.xsd '>
                    <tns:Zaglavlje>
                        <tns:IdPosiljatelja>196</tns:IdPosiljatelja>
                        <tns:TipPoruke>$TipPoruke</tns:TipPoruke>
                        <tns:IdPoruke>$UUID</tns:IdPoruke>
                        <tns:DatumVrijemeSlanja>$date_time</tns:DatumVrijemeSlanja>
                        <tns:RazinaSigurnosti>$security_level</tns:RazinaSigurnosti>
                    </tns:Zaglavlje>
                    <tns:Poruka>
                        <tns:PinPrimatelja>$OIB</tns:PinPrimatelja>
                        <tns:OznakaDrzave>$Country_code</tns:OznakaDrzave>
                        <tns:Predmet>$title</tns:Predmet>
                        <tns:Sadrzaj>$encoded_msg</tns:Sadrzaj>
                    </tns:Poruka>
                    $Attachment_file
                    </tns:KorisnickiPretinacPoruka>", XSD_ANYXML); 

            $par_envelope=array( "GsbEnvelope" =>  
                array( "MessageHeader" => 
                    array("SenderId" => "24",
                        "ServiceId" => "123",
                        "MessageId" => $UUID,
                        "SenderTimeStamp" => $date_time),
                        "Content" => array("MimeType" =>"application/xml","Data" =>array("any"=>$encodded,"encoding"=>"EMBEDDED"))));


            $par_WSDL=array("trace"=>TRUE,
                "exceptions"=>TRUE,
                'location'=>$SERVICE_TEST,
                "local_cert" =>$SOAP_cert,
                'uri'=>$NAMESPACE_URI,
                "passphrase"=>$cert_password,
                "connection_timeout" => 60);

            $client = new BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClient("GSBService.wsdl",$par_WSDL);

            $result=$client->sendMessage($par_envelope);

            //Default error code A000 == No error
            $Error_CodeK="A000";
            $Error_CodeM="A000";
            if(!empty($result->Errors)){
                $Error_CodeM=$result->Errors->Error->ErrorCode;
            }

            print_r("<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>");
            print_r("<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($xml=$client->__getLastResponse())."</p>");

            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadXML( $xml );

            $SOAPRequest = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "SifraGreske" );
                if($SOAPRequest->length!=0 || $Error_CodeM[0]!="A"){
                    if($SOAPRequest->length!=0)
                        $Error_CodeK=$SOAPRequest->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $GsbId=gen_uuid();
                    $ReceiverTimeStamp=date("c");
                }
                else 
                {
                    $SOAPRequest = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "GsbId" );
                    $GsbId = $SOAPRequest->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $SOAPRequest = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "ReplyReceivingTimeStamp" );
                    $ReceiverTimeStamp=$SOAPRequest->item(0)->nodeValue;
                }

            //Inserting errors and logins into MySQL
            error_handling_logging($UUID,$GsbId,$ReceiverTimeStamp,$OIB,$rows_lines,$Error_CodeK,$Error_CodeM,$date_time,$link_mysql);

}
```

Comment: The domain of the api looks wrong. maybe just the error message shortening it? It says `https://cis.api.` with a dot at the end. i guess a domain should be in there?

Comment: What does `var_dump($OIB_URL)` give you?

Comment: I didn't give you whole code of the script because is to long. $OIB_URL="https://e-biz.apis-it.hr:8444/kpoib/kp_lista_aktiviranih_korisnika.txt";

Comment: Ok. So what's this `https://cis.api.` in your error message then?

Comment: It is this $SERVICE_TEST = 'https://cis.apis-it.hr:8450/GSBService';

Comment: @Cikson brajo HZZO programeri na Stackoverflowu